# How to setup a django site with Cherokee, DynDNS and virtual_env?

Tags: django, dyndns, cherokee

I have a django project running with the dev server, and would like to try run it in a production environment.

I wanted to try Cherokee for a change, so I installed it. We don't have a domain name yet, so I set up a DynDNS looking like stuff.gotdns.org. It works fine, I can see the Cherokee welcome page (so red, I first believed I got an error :-p).

I ran the wizard to create a new virtual server for Django.

No everything is setup, but I have nothing. Still the default Cherokee welcome page.

What should I do now if I want to go to "http://stuff.gotdns.org" and see my website?
What should I do now if I next want to make it available only at "http://project.stuff.gotdns.org"?

Important fact, I use virtual_env, so your can call Python directly, you have to activate it first.

Answer (score 0):

More a question about whether things are working in general, does your Django app work when you're using runserver the built-in test webserver on port 8000?